# Creating two columns with an image on one side and text on the other

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">

 <RelativeLayout android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/poster"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
   <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/titleTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/byTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/dateTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/descTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="108dp"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I'm trying to achieve isto have one image spanning the height of my listView cell and on the right have my four textviews. With the code above, the app crashes.

Also, I want to specify the height of the cell, since they will all be the same. Right now, the height is predicated on the content inside.

EDIT:

Like this:

```
_______
       |  title
  Image|  by
       |  date
_______|  desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/poster"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/titleTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/byTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/dateTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/descTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tested it changing the image for another TextView and it works fine